# ASP.NET Verses Winforms

Tags: asp.net, winforms

Anyone know where i can find a good comparison between the "generally accepted" Pro's and Con's for developing in ASP.NET verses Win forms 2.0.   Preferably something official.  I need to make a presentation to my boss (not a techie at all) about the two, and am looking for something "official" to show him.  I have found lots of things on forums but cant find anything from a "offical" Source

Any Ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by official? aren't there obvious differences when you develop for web vs winforms - whether or not official?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An MSDN article that might be useful: [Choosing Between Windows Forms and Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t6z562c(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET is a web development framework, whereas WinForms is a desktop application UI framework. Are you trying to build a web site or a desktop app? There's your answer.

If your question is more in the vein of thin vs. thick clients, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522422/when-should-you-build-a-web-application-vs-a-thick-client/522431).

Comment: Agreed. And if you don't know, then it doesn't matter because you're doomed anyway.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN: [Choosing Between Windows Forms and Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t6z562c.aspx)
which also links to [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx), although you should also consider [Silveright](http://silverlight.net/) (rich apps in the browser) and [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) (alternative model to webforms at the web server).

Comment: Marc: While the link could be useful, I think the basic differences should be meaningful to a non-technical person. Am I rude in adding my comments to the OP?

Comment: No, I don't see any "rude". But don't forget, there's non-technical, and then there's managers ;-p